# Gradle downloading "Sendbird android github library" every time

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, sendbird

I am using Sendbird android SDK in my project(https://docs.sendbird.com/android).
Its library is hosted on GitHub, the problem is every time I change in gradle it takes 15-20 minutes to compile and it shows it is downloading so many files.
My question is why it is not using cache or downloaded library like other libraries and how to reduce the time of compilation.

#### app module build.gradle file screenshot

[image: app module build.gradle file screenshot]

#### Github repository URL in progress

[image: Github repository URL]

Comment: It's downloading Firebase...

Answer (score 2):

This is the way Gradle works from my experience. After your first build, you can enable "Offline mode" in Android Studio so that it will use cached libraries. But when you add another library you will have to disable "Offline mode" to download it.

To enable "Offline mode", press Ctrl-Shift-A and type "Offline work" then press Enter. Then check the highlighted checkbox in the Settings window and click OK.

Comment: What I believe is gradle checks for new versions, everytime it is synced but it should not download the whole library. if it downloads all files everytime something changes in build.gradle file then other libraries should have taken time too.